# How background color will stay if the page refreshes or table updates

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

When a costumer orders his/her orders will be save into the database which all items are `Pending` and I am the one who will approve or cancel his/her orders. When I clicked `Approve button`, the Pending order will be `Delivered` and if `Cancel button`, the order will be `Cancelled`. Now I want css `success` for all td's that were "Delivered" and css `danger` for those that were Canceled. And background color's stays even I refresh the page.

This is my table looks like this:

```
Date Ordered         Order No.     Total item(s) Total Amount   Order Status
 09-11-2015      15-09-0000000001        3          213.85        Pending
 09-11-2015      15-09-0000000002        1          130.00        Pending
 09-11-2015      15-09-0000000003        2          134.07        Pending
 09-11-2015      15-09-0000000004        4          846.41        Pending

       <button>Approve Order</button> <button>Cancel Order</button>
```

This is my PHP

As you can see my td (`order_status`). I want to call that `success` in my `css` if the `order_status` was "Delivered" when I clicked the `Approve button`. And if the order_status was "Cancelled" by clicking the `Cancel button`, call `danger` in my `css`.

So am I going to do if else if statement?

```
<?php
    if(!session_id()){
        session_start();
    }
    include_once '../fileadmin/dbinit.php';
    $todo = $_POST['todo'];
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","atec_coop");
    if (!$con){
        die("Can't connect".mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("atec_coop",$con);
    switch ($todo) {
        case "display":
            $sql = "SELECT * from tb_empgroc_master";
//            $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
            $result = $atecCoop->query($sql);

            $html = ''; $ctr = 0;
            if ($result->num_rows){
                while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                $id = $row->empgrocmstID;
                $date_ordered = date("m-d-Y");
                $order_no = date($row->order_no);
                $total_items = number_format($row->total_items);
                $total_amount = number_format($row->total_amount,2);
                $order_status = wordwrap($row->order_status);
                $Order = $row->empgrocmstID;

                $html .= "<tr id='$id'>";
                $html .= "<td class='date_ordered' style='text-align:center'>$date_ordered</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='order_no' style='text-align:center'>$order_no</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='total_items' style='text-align:right'>$total_items</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='total_amount' style='text-align:right'>$total_amount</td>";
                $html .= "<td id='$Order' class='order_status' style='text-align:center'>$order_status</td>";
                $html .= "</tr>";
                }
            }
            echo $html;
        break;
        case "Cancel":
            $Cancelquery = "UPDATE tb_empgroc_master SET order_status='Cancelled' WHERE empgrocmstID='".$_POST['empgrocmstID']."'";
            mysql_query($Cancelquery, $con);
        break;
        case "Approve":
            $Approvequery = "UPDATE tb_empgroc_master SET order_status='Delivered' WHERE empgrocmstID='".$_POST['empgrocmstID']."'";
            mysql_query($Approvequery, $con);
        break;
    }
?>
```

This is my ajax call for button

As you can see that commented `css`. That works but When I refresh the page the `background color's` gone. I've commented that `updateTable();` also because the `background color's` gone because the table updates. So I want td `background color` to stay even if I refresh the page.

```
$("#Approve").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#cLoanOut tr.active').attr('id');
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to approve order?","No","Yes",function(r){
        if(r) {
            $.ajax({  
                url : "<?php echo $server_name; ?>/emcis_coopmain/process/PHP_groceryReleasingProcess.php",
                type : "POST",
                async : false,
                data : {
                    empgrocmstID:id,
                    todo:"Approve"
                },
                success:function(result){
//                                $('tr.active td.order_status').css("background-color", "green");
                    bootbox.alert('Order Approved',function(){
                    $("#Approve").attr("disabled", true);
                    });
//                                updateTable();
                }
            });   
        } else {

        }
    });
});
$("#Cancel").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#cLoanOut tr.active').attr('id');
//                var x = $('table tr.active').find('td.class').html();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel order?","No","Yes",function(r){
        if(r) {
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo $server_name; ?>/emcis_coopmain/process/PHP_groceryReleasingProcess.php",
                type : "POST",
                async : false,
                data : {
                    empgrocmstID:id,
                    todo:"Cancel"
                },
                success:function(result){
//                                $('tr.active td.order_status').css("background-color", "red");
                    bootbox.alert("Order Cancelled",function(){
                    $("#Cancel").attr("disabled", true);
                    });
//                                updateTable();
                }
            });   
        } else {

        }
    });
});
```

This is my CSS

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
    background-color: #607d8b;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
div.well{
    background-color: #fff9c4;
    color: #000000;
}
#cLoanOut .active{
    background-color: #2c9e94;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active > td.danger:hover {
     background-color: red !important;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active > td.warning:hover {
     background-color: yellow !important;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active > td.success:hover {
     background-color: green !important;
}
```

And my Form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="main-form" action="PHP_groceryReleasingProcess.php" method="POST">
    <table class="tablesorter table table-bordered table-condensed" id="cLoanOut" style="table-layout: fixed;">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="110">
            <col width="130">
            <col width="50">
            <col width="60">
            <col width="90">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date Ordered</th>
                <th>Order No.</th>
                <th>Total Item(s)</th>
                <th>Total Amount</th>
                <th>Order Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="Approve" role="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled>Approve Order</button>
    <button id="Cancel" role="button" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>Cancel Order</button>
</form>
```

I want to call that `danger` and `success` in my `CSS` in a specific td. 'empgrocmstID' is an auto increment field in the database. I know how to call success and danger by putting it in td of `order_status`... `class='order_status success'`, `class='order_status danger'` but that's not the point.
 I've tried this code inside the case "display" but the td's of `order_status` won't show.

```
if ($order_status===''){
    $html .= "<td id='$Order' class='order_status success' style='text-align:center'>$order_status</td>";
}else if($order_status===''){
    $html .= "<td id='$Order' class='order_status danger' style='text-align:center'>$order_status</td>";
}
```

I appreciate your help thanks

Comment: The `.php` file seems not big enough to assume you wrote it a long time ago, so knowing today **MySQLi** or **PDO** connection to database in PhP are _way_ more safer than [deprecated mysql_* functions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php), you should turn the code to enable the 2 first and safer connection I mentioned. Also, it should have send the `E_DEPRECATED` value using `mysql_connect()`, did you disabled these ?

Comment: No it's not a duplicate. @Epodax

Comment: Please read. Don't be bored to read my explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make annother row in your database where you have the status. Judt make it 1=approved and 2=not approved.
Now you can make a simple if and echo it with 2 different css

Comment: If I will have another field which is order status. I will have 2 rows of Pending orders.

Comment: @Micaela how do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your last bit of PHP code is confusing because you are testing if `$order_status` is an empty string. This would explain why you don't see the `td` of order_status anymore.

With the same idea, just to this :

```
$html .= "<td id='$Order' class='order_status ".strtolower($order_status)."' style='text-align:center'>$order_status</td>";
```

This will print directly the value of `order_status` in the class attribute, no need for your to test.

Also, in your javascript you are changing the css of the td. Instead you should just add the value of order_status to the class of the td.

```
$('tr.active td.order_status').addClass("success");
```